# Cannot convert overloaded function pointer to member function pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have code as following

```
class A
{
public:
    int Key() const;
};

class B : public A
{};

template<class T, int (T::*MemFunction)() const>
class TT
{
public:
    int Get() const               {return (m_t.*MemFunction)();}

private:
    T m_t;
};

TT<B, &B::Key> t; // Wrong, cannot convert overloaded function
                  // to int (T::*MemFunction)() (VS2010)
```

Why and how to a similar way works? Thanks

Comment: how do  you call B::key in TT?

Comment: I think it does't matter with the question. But I added some code to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cast should make it work:

```
typedef int (B::*Key)() const;
TT<Key(&B::Key)> t;
t.Get();
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer has already been provided by billz, but I will try to produce an explanation.

In C++ when obtaining a pointer to member, the result of the expression is not a pointer to member of the type present in the expression, but rather a pointer-to-member of the type where the member is defined. That is, the expression `&B::Key` yields `&A::Key`, as the member function `Key` is defined in `A` and not in `B`. This is defined in §5.3.1/3, which is hard to read but comes with an example:

> The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a qualified-id. If the operand is a qualified-id naming a non-static member m of some class C with type T, the result has type “pointer to member of class C of type T” and is a prvalue designating C::m. Otherwise, if the type of the expression is T, the result has type “pointer to T” and is a prvalue that is the address of the designated object (1.7) or a pointer to the designated function. [ Note: In particular, the address of an object of type “cv T” is “pointer to cv T”, with the same cv-qualification. — end note ] [ Example:

```
struct A { int i; };
struct B : A { };
... &B::i ... // has type int A::*
```

> — end example ]

This means that your template instantiation is equivalent to:

```
TT<B, &A::Key>
```

While a pointer-to-member to a member of a base can be converted to a pointer-to-member to the a derived type, for the particular case of a non-type non-template template parameter that conversion is not allowed. The conversions for non-type non-template template parameters are defined in §14.3.2/5, which for this particular case states:

> For a non-type template-parameter of type pointer to member function, if the template-argument is of type std::nullptr_t, the null member pointer conversion (4.11) is applied; otherwise, no conversions apply.

Since the `&A::Key` cannot be converged to `int (B::*)() const`, the template instantiation is ill-formed. By adding the cast in the template instantiation you are forcing the conversion to happen before instantiating the template, and the instantiation becomes valid as there is no need for conversiones.